# Getting "cURL cannot communicate with license server" when installing Plesk in a GCP instance

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, plesk, web-application-firewall

I'm trying to activate a new Plesk license on a CentOS instance on Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine instance. On the Plesk activation screen, I add my activation code and then receive this error:

*cURL cannot communicate with license server https://id-00.kaid.plesk.com:443/ (195.214.233.82): Couldn't connect to server(7) cURL cannot communicate with license server https://id-00.kaid.plesk.com:443/ (): Couldn't resolve host name(6) (Error code: 2)*

I then followed the instructions at https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000256834-Cannot-install-Plesk-license-key-WordPress-plugin-or-a-Plesk-extension-cURL-cannot-communicate-with-license-server at the bottom in the GCP area and I created a firewall rule on GCP like this below, but still unable to communicate and activate. I already asked Plesk support and they said it was a firewall issue. Any idea how to solve this?

```
Priority: 10
Direction: Egress
Action on match: Allow
Destination filters | IP Ranges: 195.214.233.80 195.214.233.81 195.214.233.82
Protocols and ports: tcp:5224 tcp:443
Enforcement: Enabled
```

Comment: do you have other firewall rules? Can you try to ping id-00.kaid.plesk.com and see if the DNS works at least?

Comment: $ ping id-00.kaid.plesk.com
PING ka.plesk.com (195.214.233.80) 56(84) bytes of data.

And then it hangs for many minutes on that and returns nothing so far after about 5 minutes....

Yes I have other firewalls. They were installed by default in GCP. My Plesk used to work fine actually and only realized it wasn't working finer after I tried to install a new Plesk license. Not sure how long it has been "off" for the firewall...

Answer (score 0):

Probably your firewall rule is not attached to your instance. Check that your Source Filters is IP range and is set to either your instance IP, the subnetwork of your instance or 0.0.0.0/0 to apply to every instance in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I install by SSH the Licence:

Reference:

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004139594-cURL-error-6-Could-not-resolve-host-example-com-Name-or-service-not-known

Command:

```
plesk bin license -i *AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE*
```

Your Licence, You can ask your supplier hosting.